# Embedding API returns status 200 and statusText OK but does not return data

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

I am sending NodeJs request to OpenAI Embedding API. The response returns me status 200 and statusText 'OK' but does not provide me the embedding list of the text.

My Code

```
    try {
        await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings", {
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${OPENAI_TOKEN}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body" : JSON.stringify({
                input, 
                model
              })
        }).then ( async (rawResponse)  => {
            console.log("response ", rawResponse)
            // console.log("response ", rawResponse.data.data[0].embedding)
            console.log("response from open ai" , JSON.stringify(rawResponse))
            const response = await rawResponse.json()
            
        }).catch ( (err) => {
            console.log ("error at open ai ", err)
        })
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error at ", e)
    }
}
```

Response

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 200,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 717.670324,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 717.670324,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 212,
      decodedBodySize: 0,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'OK',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: [Array],
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ URL {} ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: [
      '__cf_bm=i5G3g.nPl_2uJLY2uTZ6KTpFC6YOmcnIxvLu95XJ9U0-1705706294-1-AQuKQ25HtTTt/2HQ75sk5+OFvYgJy86JHZbWGOjpN08oW64JcKCfNLNZBlc5Bx9cBerc7JIlN/oRfxzXk/86FSM=; path=/; expires=Fri, 19-Jan-24 23:48:14 GMT; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None',
      '_cfuvid=mKHeA1p.GJrKNF_5IrK4NPxgAiA1986dHTuy7ZBJkDY-1705706294278-0-604800000; path=/; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None'
    ],
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(22) {
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'transfer-encoding' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'access-control-allow-origin' => [Object],
      'openai-organization' => [Object],
      'openai-processing-ms' => [Object],
      'openai-version' => [Object],
      'strict-transport-security' => [Object],
      'x-ratelimit-limit-requests' => [Object],
      'x-ratelimit-limit-tokens' => [Object],
      'x-ratelimit-remaining-requests' => [Object],
      'x-ratelimit-remaining-tokens' => [Object],
      'x-ratelimit-reset-requests' => [Object],
      'x-ratelimit-reset-tokens' => [Object],
      'x-request-id' => [Object],
      'cf-cache-status' => [Object],
      'set-cookie' => [Object],
      'server' => [Object],
      'cf-ray' => [Object],
      'content-encoding' => [Object],
      'alt-svc' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

Sending the same request with curl works!
Also, while you are it, I want to create embeddings for multiple text strings stored in a csv file. Is there a better way that to send one request / row so that I don't reach the rate limits of the OpenAI

I tried curl request which worked. I am expecting a list of embeddings.